# DataGrip and DBeaver (Java based db IDEs) error when connecting to the database

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, datagrip, dbeaver

I can connect to the database via MySQL Workbench and VStudio (Valentina Studio) or phpMyAdmin, but I have problems with DBeaver and DataGrip - porbably the Java programs use some different settings?

For example, in DataGrip, I am getting this error when connecting to the mysql database:

`Connection to @example.test failed: SSH: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1.
SSH: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1`

Any idea what it could be and how to fix it - perhaps adjust some settings?

I am running the `DataGrip-2017.1.2` on Linux 64-bit.

I am using Vagrant for the server on my local machine, so, maybe some Vagrant setting is to blame? But Workbench, Valentina Studio and phpMyAdmin have no problem to connect to the database.

Comment: it seams that the port number is not correct, can you check the port please?

Comment: The port field in DataGrip is empty but in Workbench I have 3306 , so, I have tried that and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @YCF_L If I test ssh connection I get: `SSH Connection to @example.test failed: SSH: invalid server's version string.`

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when **Port** is empty. Please try filling in the port of your SSH server. Usually, it is `22`.